# Select MAX(timestamp) GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+----+----------+---------+--------+-------+---------------------+
| id | order_id | user_id | status | notes | timestamp           |
+----+----------+---------+--------+-------+---------------------+
|  3 |        1 |       0 |      0 |       | 2015-11-29 22:49:44 |
|  4 |        1 |       0 |      2 |       | 2015-11-29 22:51:51 |
|  5 |        2 |       0 |      0 |       | 2015-11-29 23:14:26 |
|  6 |        3 |       0 |      0 |       | 2015-11-29 23:15:52 |
+----+----------+---------+--------+-------+---------------------+
```

Why is the following query:

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    `status`,
    MAX(timestamp)
FROM
    order_status
GROUP BY
    order_id
```

Returning the following result?

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+
| order_id | status | MAX(timestamp)      |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
|        1 |      0 | 2015-11-29 22:51:51 |
|        2 |      0 | 2015-11-29 23:14:26 |
|        3 |      0 | 2015-11-29 23:15:52 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

Shouldn't line 1 have status = 2?

Comment: No, because it doesn't return the corresponding status, it returns the first  (sometimes)in the group (you should apply additional logic to the status field).

Comment: This happens because of how certain versions of MySQL handles the `group by` clause. See this section in the MySQL reference manual for an explanation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it returns anything at all is due to a quirk in MySQL.  After all, what value should be returned for `status`?  It is not included in the `GROUP BY`.  So, MySQL returns a value from an indeterminate row.  Most other databases would simply return an error.

Try something like:

```
select os.*
from order_status os
where timestamp = (select max(os2.time_stamp)
                   from order_status os2
                   where os2.order_id = os.order_id
                  );
```

Comment: I was really under the impression that I didn't need a subselect for this, but thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is very old but was my first result in google search when researching. 
You do not need a sub select, this is the correct way to solve this.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT (order_id),
    status,
    timestamp
FROM
    order_status
ORDER BY order_id, timestamp DESC
```